# Spring Batch how to regroup/aggregate user datas into a single object

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to transform user operations (like purshases) into a user summary class (expenses by user). A user can have multiple operations but only one summary. I cannot sum purshases in the reader because I need a processor to reject some operation depending to another service.

So some code :

```
class UserOperation {
  String userId;
  Integer price;
}

class UserSummary {
  String userId;
  Long sum;
}

@Bean
public Step retrieveOobClientStep1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<UserOperation> userInformationJdbcCursorItemReader, ItemProcessor<UserOperation, UserSummary> userInformationsProcessor, ItemWriter<UserSummary> flatFileWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step1").<UserOperation, UserSummary>chunk(100) // chunck result that need to be aggregated... not good
        .reader(userInformationJdbcCursorItemReader) // read all user operations from DB
        .processor(userInformationsProcessor) // I need to reject or not some operations - but here 1 operation = 1 summary that is not good
        .writer(flatFileWriter) // write result into flat file
        .build();
}
```

I thing that ItemReader/ItemProcessor/ItemWriter is for single item processing. 
But how to regroup multiples records into a single object using Spring Batch ? only Tasklet ?

**Possibility but cause problems with small commit interval** :

```
public class UserSummaryAggregatorItemStreamWriter implements ItemStreamWriter<UserSummary>, InitializingBean {

    private ItemStreamWriter<UserSummary> delegate;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(delegate, "'delegate' may not be null.");
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemStreamWriter<UserSummary> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends UserSummary> items) throws Exception {

        Map<String, UserSummary> userSummaryMap = new HashMap<String, UserSummary>();

        // Aggregate
        for (UserSummary item : items) {
            UserSummary savedUserSummary = userSummaryMap.get(item.getUserId());
            if (savedUserSummary != null) {
                savedUserSummary.incrementSum(item.getSum()); // sum
            } else {
                savedUserSummary = item;
            }
            userSummaryMap.put(item.getSubscriptionCode(), savedUserSummary);
        }

        Collection<UserSummary> values = userSummaryMap.values();
        if(values != null) {
            delegate.write(new ArrayList<UserSummary>(values));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(executionContext);        
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);      
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();       
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html. Check 11.3.1 - Writing a Summary Footer

Comment: Will you have multiple summaries per output or just one?  If just one, see Luca's response above.  If you'll have multiple, I'll have a different answer.

Comment: Yes, Luca's response help me a lot. Another question, what's about chunck with edited solution ? (does aggregation works with a small commit interval ?)

Comment: I have tried with a small commit interval (`chunk(2)`), that not works... Because items are written before all others have been processed.